# How to monitor progress in Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, task-parallel-library

I'm using `Parallel.ForEach` to download 500K Urls and I want to monitor how many Urls have been successfully downloaded each minute. I'm now using a lock statement inside the Parallel.ForEach loop to output the number of Urls downloaded every minute:

```
int elapsedMinutes = 0, cnt = 0;
Parallel.ForEach(list, tuple =>
{
    var currMinutes = (int) ((DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalMinutes);
    lock (Object)
    {
        if (currMinutes > elapsedMinutes)
        {
            elapsedMinutes = currMinutes;
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: Extracted {1} urls", DateTime.Now, cnt);
        }
    }

    //download urls ...

    Interlocked.Increment(ref cnt);
});
```

But I'm concerned over the lock statement part would affect perf a bit. Are there any other approaches to achieve this?

Comment: This might be better asked on Code Review http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @MikeCaron Thanks Mike. I've reworded my question. Please let me know if this fits SO better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than asking every single parallel task to synchronize itself with all of the others just create a separate resource (a `Timer` appears to be the best tool here) that can check the count of completed operations every minute, leaving your loop only needing to increment a counter.

Comment: Thanks Servy. This indeed is a simpler approach. :)